# Using dbplyr and across to find the number of missing values in a SQL table

Tags: r, dbplyr

I'm trying to use dbplyr to calculate the number of missing rows across all columns in a database.  The database is an Azure Synapse SQL database.

I have a simple table with one column, "MyColumn" for testing purposes and use:

```
b = a %>% summarise(across(everything(), ~ sum(is.na(.))))
```

But unfortunately get the error:

> Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1655: 42000: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for
> SQL Server][SQL Server] Parse error at line: 1, column: 45: Incorrect
> syntax near 'IS'.   'SELECT TOP 11 SUM(CAST(IIF((("MyColumn") IS
> NULL), 1, 0) AS BIT)) AS "MyColumn" FROM (SELECT "MyColumn" FROM
> "dbo"."MyTable") "q01"'

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?

I'm using dbplyr 2.1.1

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Based on the error message this is the SQL query that your dplyr commands are being translated into:

```sql
SELECT TOP 11 SUM(CAST(IIF((("MyColumn") IS NULL), 1, 0) AS BIT)) AS "MyColumn"
FROM (
    SELECT "MyColumn"
    FROM "dbo"."MyTable"
) "q01"
```

If you can run this query directly in SQL, then it will tell you why it is failing.

Two possibilities come to mind:

1. Some flavors of SQL object to `SUM` on a column of type `BIT`.
2. `across` may not translate perfectly with dbplyr.

Of these, it is most likely the first point, the work around is to use `ifelse`:

```r
b = a %>% summarise(across(everything(), ~ sum(ifelse(is.na(.), 1, 0))))
```

Because `ifelse` will return numeric values rather than `BIT` values.

Comment: Thank you, I think it's the IIF statement not working in Azure Synapse SQL

For example running the following in SQL directly throws an error:

SELECT IIF(1>2, 'YES', 'NO');

Appreciate the help - I'll see if I can file a bug report

Comment: Sorry, but without knowing what error this gives you I doubt I can help further.